# Compilation problem for C++ program

Tags: 12.04, apt, gcc, g++

How do I install `g++` or `pentium builder` packages? Do I need to download those?

Because when I try to compile the program and with this statement:

```
g++ -Wall -W -Werror main.cpp -o HelloWorldCPP`
```

This is showing that it needs packages, i.e. g++ and pentium builder, so what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Just run

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

in the terminal to install all common packages required for compiling native C/C++ software. This is a *metapackage*, installing several *actual* packages you will need (including gcc/g++).

Alternatively, you can install this by clicking this link to install via software centre: [`build-essential`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) [image: Install build-essential]